# Creating and opening a new Document using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I know I can use

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
```

to create a new document on GoogleDocs, but how do I create it on a specific folder?

Further more, how do I write a code to open the newly created document? I´ve searched 
[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#create(String)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#create%28String%29), but I could not find the answer.

Thank You Very Much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your code can get an instance of an already existing Document, and is used for script running "inside" the document (custom options, functions, etc.)

To create a new document instead, use:

```
// Create and open a document.
doc = DocumentApp.create('Document Name');
```

this works in any script.

To move the document on a specific folder, you have the method:

```
myFolder.addFile(doc);
```

For more info, look at DriveApp, DocumentApp, Document, File, Folder reference.

Comment: Is there a way of running the script without opening it from a Document?

Comment: the snippets above can run on any script: DriveApp or DocumentApp are standalone "factory" classes. Only methods like getActiveDocument() can run only from a Document that is currently opened by the user.

Comment: Look also at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339500/how-to-fetch-the-id-of-a-google-spread-sheet-via-google-apps-script/18892153#18892153) that explains the differences between document id in Document/Spreadsheet App and DriveApp