# Inserting Google Spreadsheet ID in cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-custom-function

Attempting to insert the value of the spreadsheet ID, and sheet/tab IDs into cells in my spreadsheet.

Found this answer and tried the code as a script:

[How to fetch the ID of a Google Spread Sheet via Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339500/how-to-fetch-the-id-of-a-google-spread-sheet-via-google-apps-script)

Then I ran into this error when I tried to run it as a cell-based function:

> Error You do not have permission to call msgBox (line 2).

As per [No permission to call msgBox in Google Apps Scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506105/no-permission-to-call-msgbox-in-google-apps-scripting).

Hoping there might be a workaround and/or proper way to do this that someone could point out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No permission to call msgBox in Google Apps Scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506105/no-permission-to-call-msgbox-in-google-apps-scripting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a custom function to write a value to the cell, you can just use `return` to write the value to the cell.

So your modified function would be

```
function getId() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()
}
```